# Initialize variables with keras

Tags: python, keras

I am training a model with tensorflow.keras `model.fit` function.

Do I need to initialize variables before training?

If I call

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    init=tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
```

and then

```
model.fit()
```

does keras session takes count of previous initialized variables?
Or does it initialize them for its own?

Comment: There is no need to create session and initialize the variables. Keras handles it internally.